# Laravel jobs - Accessing modified property values from failed() method after job has failed

Tags: php, laravel

Is there a way to access a modified property value in a Laravel job after the job has failed? When I `dd()` the missing items array within the `failed()` method after pushing an item into it while the job is processing, I get the initial property value of an empty array returned, rather than the array with an item pushed into it.

If this can't be done, is it acceptable to create a custom exception and which accepts custom data as a parameter? I can then add a `getData()` method to my custom exception and call this within `failed()` to get my modified property value.

By the way, I haven't pasted the actual job class below as it would be quite large but this simulates what I'm hoping to achieve.

I hope I've explained this well enough.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class PushOrdersToAnotherService implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $missingItems = [];

    public function handle()
    {
        // ...

        if (true) {
            $this->missingItems[] = ['name' => 'Some item'];
            throw new Exception('Items were missing', 400);
        }
    }

    public function failed(Exception $exception)
    {
        dd($this->missingItems); // Returns []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) Simply you can define `$missingItems` variable as **static** variable as below.

```
protected static $missingItems = [];
```

2.) You can modify it inside the `handle()` function as below.

```
public function handle()
{
  // ...

  if (true) {
    self::$missingItems[] = ['name' => 'Some item'];
    throw new Exception('Items were missing', 400);
  }
}
```

3.) Then you can check that inside the `failed()` function as below.

```
public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
  dd(self::$missingItems); // Returns ['name' => 'Some item']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and didn't find a native solution. So I've made a workaround by creating a service for caching the data:

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Jobs\Job;

class JobFailService
{
    /**
     * @var Job
     */
    public $job;

    /**
     * @var JobFailService
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * @return JobFailService
     */
    public static function factory()
    {
        if (!self::$instance)
        {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

In the `handle()` method of my job class I did the following:

```
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $jobFailService = JobFailService::factory();
        $jobFailService->job = $this;
    }
```

And in the `failed()` method this:

```
/**
 * @param Exception $exception
 */
final public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    $jobFailService = JobFailService::factory(); 
}
```

`$jobFailService->job` contains the running job, not the serialized constructed one